# Programmatically accessing files within a zip file?

Tags: linux, zip, gzip

Can I access a file/folder within a zip file without extracting it to a temporary file?

This is on a linux system.

Right now, I just need to "read" from the file, but is it possible to "write" to it as well?

---

Edit 1: Sorry for not clarifying, I was hoping for a command line tool that would allow it to work from any language, but as an alternate, a PHP solution / toolkit is what I would need.

Comment: Writing is a lot of work. The new compressed data may not be the same size as the old data, and zip stores its directory at the end so appending files is not trivial either.

Comment: Hmm  - so possibly, we can "pipe" the output of a file from the command line for another program to use, but cant pipe the input from something "into" the zip file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the language, but Java has a whole library that can be used to read and write to a zip file.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

For a C or C++, you'll have to use a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

For C or C++, use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) with [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html).